# How to get the os name of selected computer in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

i want to get the os information for the selected computer name or ip address.

i have the list view to display the computers name in LAN,How to get the Selected computer's 
os details ie (which os,username of the computer)

how to do this in vb.net?

Answer (score 3):

You could use WMI. [Here's an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms257337(VS.80).aspx).

Comment: i have used the same code for connecting other system
it shows

" Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"

please help me

Comment: You need to run this code under an administrative account that has access to the remote computer.

Comment: i run this code under an administrative account,but error shows

Comment: The account needs administrative privileges on the **remote** machine, not the local.

Comment: How to get the vista installed system in workgroup using vb.net